# if command is true for X seconds run code in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, time, boolean

i want an if statement to only run if the condition in the statement is true for at least 3 consecutive seconds, how do i achieve it in linux bash shell script?
i haven't done it before, and couldn't find anything specific by googling and would greatly appreciate any help!
i don't mean like a loop that executes the condition x amount of times, but a function that checks of the condition is true for at least x consecutive seconds/minutes before it runs a block of code.

thanks in advance

Comment: bash doesn't really have any notion of monitoring conditions over time. You might be able to check it repeatedly until 3 seconds have passed, or if there's a command that monitors it you could use that, but I don't think there's anything like that directly in bash. What are you trying to monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You could define this function:

```sh
check_cond() {
    local stop=$(($(date +%s)+3))
    while :; do
        cond && return 1
        [ $(date +%s) -gt $stop ] && break
    done
}
```

It returns 1 if `cond` is false within the 3 second time period. It returns 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check it once, wait 3 sec and check again, something like this

```
$ test=
 [[ $test ]] && { sleep 3; [[ $test ]]; } && echo ok || echo fail
fail

$ test=1
$ [[ $test ]] && { sleep 3; [[ $test ]]; } && echo ok || echo fail
ok
```